How to scroll down in cell with a lot of text
I have a dataset with extremely long text data (and many newlines).
I've created a mock-up here:

You can see that there's a 5th Lorem Ipsum paragraph at the top, but I can't seem to get it to display down below. I've tried pressing the down arrow or the End command while editing to jump to the bottom paragraph, but the cursor just disappears and it doesn't scroll.
Is there any way for me to edit this longer text and see what I'm editing as I'm editing it, including newlines? (I know I can edit using the top bar, but not being able to see the whitespace is difficult because I'm building an NLP dataset, so I need to make sure data is consistent.)
I can't do this in Excel because the text in some of my cells exceeds 33k characters, which goes past Excel's limit, but not LibreOffice's. However, now I'm running into this display issue with LibreOffice that still makes it very difficult to view the text.
Version info:
Version: 7.6.7.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: dd47e4b30cb7dab30588d6c79c651f218165e3c5
CPU threads: 16; OS: Windows 10.0 Build 19045; UI render: Skia/Raster; VCL: win
Locale: en-US (en_US); UI: en-US
Calc: CL threaded
